# html table size changed by IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a problem with IE9 and an html table. I have a page with tables beside each others (float: left;), the size of cells of all tables is fixed by CSS. On chrome when the row is full, the new table go on the next line, but on IE the table is shrunk (cell size not respected).
How to force line jumping on IE (no size reducing)?

Comment: Please post your code, and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: Without knowing the html code it is hard to guess, but the css property `table-layout:fixed` could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table-layout:fixed` on `<table>` and `min-height`, `min-width` on `<td>` solve the probleme.

Thank you